# Visual Studio 2017 Conditional Compilation Symbols not Working for Publish

Tags: c#, build, visual-studio-2017, conditional-compilation

I'm developing a C# Web Application with VS 2017. I'm using Conditional Compilation Symbols to set variables to different values for my Debug, Test and Release builds. When I do a build on my development machine, exerything works fine. When I try to publish my solution, the Conditional Compilation Symbols are not set. I now this because I get a compiler error stating the constants I set in the conditonal compilations clauses are not set.

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Comment: Did you set the conditionals for release configuration?

Comment: Thanks. I published with the release configuration and it now works for all configurations. Go figure..

Answer (score 0):

I published with the release configuration and it now works for all configurations. Go figure...